Apple signup in Android flutter
I'm encountering an issue with implementing Apple Sign-In on Android in my Flutter application. When I redirect to the Apple login webpage, I receive an "Invalid Client" error.
I've already configured the appropriate settings for Android, including the necessary adjustments in the AndroidManifest.xml. The Apple Sign-In works perfectly on iOS devices, but I can't figure out why it's not working on Android.
Has anyone else experienced this issue or know what might be causing it? Any help would be appreciated!
